# Does pilot need to increase thrust when gust hit him at landing and where is axis of rotation?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, stability

Let's say a plane is flying above a runway in straight line, and gust of wind hits the plane from side.
Do pilot need increase thrust to stay above runway and where is axis of rotation ?

It often said that all object rotate around c.g. does it mean that axis of rotation passes through plane c.g. or somewhere else?

My interest is from the view of an observer seeing this encounter standing under the plane - a view from a ground-based frame of reference.

Comment: What are you trying to get from the answer? Because the gust of wind will cause the aircraft to change it attitude but it will also change it speed vector. So there will be a combination of rotation and translation. The combination will not necessarilly scale linearly with the magnitude of the gust. And in which reference frame do you want to define this axis? The aircraft moves with respect to the earth and with respect to air. Do you want to define the axis in the aircraft frame of reference, the earth frame of reference or the air frame of reference?

Comment: @DeltaLima ref. frame earth

Comment: "*gust of wind hit plane from side*" what does it mean from side? Suddenly the whole side surface? Only the tail? Only the nose? Is it an assignment? What's your opinion?

Comment: @sophit yes all surface

Comment: Adding thrust will cause the plane to rise.  Pilots generally increase bank to hold against wind.  But for planes with very long wings, there is a danger of wing tip strike.

Comment: By a [physics point of view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271109/why-can-any-general-motion-of-a-rigid-body-be-represented-as-translation-rotat) it can be demonstrated that the movement of a rigid body (like an aircraft) can always be represented as the sum of a translation plus a rotation of its centre of mass. So yes, due to the gust, the airplane is going to rotate around its center of mass and its center of mass is going to shift. How exactly depends on how the gust looks like.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni But when gust hit, plane is blown downwind from runway?

Comment: @user628075 yes, of course, and if your plane rotates into the wind adding thrust will help you hold line.  But why do that when sideforce can be created by banking?  Thrust will increase your airspeed.  The plane won't want to land.

Answer (score 2):

The aircraft doesn’t rotate around a particular axis, it will be blown downwind and will rotate, so you can choose any axis that’s meaningful to you.  The centre of gravity might be useful in many cases.

Comment: plane change orientation so it must rotate around some  axis

Comment: Relative to the ground, the axis will be a long way ahead of the aircraft and will move relative to both the ground and the aircraft, but this is unlikely to be useful to identify for any practical purpose.